# The Django make ORM query

Tags: python, django, orm, model

```
class Task(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    reward = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    begin_date = models.DateField()
    number_of_people = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class TaskDetail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tasks')
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='tasks')
```

This is a simple task assignment system model designed by me.
and I have a question.I attempt to make a user report that include the number of task user've done.but I don't know how to make ORM query.

```
users = User.objects.all
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that you are trying to count the tasks that a user with `id=1` has accomplished.

```
the_user = User.objects.filter(id=1)  # Does not hit the database
data = TaskDetail.objects.filter(user__in=the_user) # It selects all tasks by the user
result = data.count()  #It hits the database to count
print(result)
```

Here are the relevant [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships).

However, you can just use one table -if this is the complete layout- and put the `user` `ForeignKey` to the table `Task` as a `ManyToManyField`.

The way you have built it, it is possible to have stray tasks because a user forgot to assign the task to himself.

Comment: I'll try to implement ManyToManyField at my models.py, Thank you so much~

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of giving `related_name` with `user` column in `TaskDetail` model. 
by using `foreign_key` there is no need to build another query. You can use chain concept:

```
users = User.objects.all()
task_details = TaskDetail.objects.filter(user=users)
for task_detail in task_details:
    subject = task_detail.task.subject
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by 2 way(have some diffrents):

**1.get** :

```
users = User.objects.get(username = "jack" and email= "jack@gmail.com")
```

**note**:in this example we have `username` and `password` field

**2.filter** :

```
users = User.objects.filter(username = "jack")
```

**The differences** :

in the `filter` use:

you can use `.exists()` or `.count()` or `.first()` or `.last()` (and some other querys)

for exmaple:

```
posts_count = Post.objects.filter(owner="jack").count()
```

it will show you the count of post have owner name `jack`

**but** in `get` you can't use `.exists()` or `.count()` or `.first()` or `.last()` (and some other querys)